# How can I create a UITableViewCell like a UITextField?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, uikit

How can I create a `UITableViewCell` like a `UITextField` programmatically or using Interface Builder?

I tried with Interface Builder but it seems it doesn't work:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Subclass UITableViewCell and add a UITextField to the cell's contentView. You probably won't get your result without creating your own tableViewCell.

example:

MyAwesomeTextfieldCell.h

```
@interface MyAwesomeTextfieldCell : UITableViewCell
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *labelTextView;
@end
```

MyAwesomeTextfieldCell.m

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        _labelTextView = [[UITextField alloc] init];
        _labelTextView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        _labelTextView.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17.0];
        _labelTextView.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [self addSubview:_labelTextView];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: sorry i would to say how can i create UITextField like a UITableViewCell programmatically or using Interface Builder?

Comment: Take a look at my example. That's a way to do it programmatically. Of course you can also do it with Interface Builder. Just add a nib to your custom class.

Answer (score 0):

```
static NSString * kCellReuse = @"CellReuseIdentifier"
UITableViewCell * cell  = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:kCellReuse];
```